# Dojo: All Scrollable Views are getting rendered together on Application launch

Tags: ios, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I build one application using Worklight 6.0.0 and DOJO. Its is working fine on Browser but when i installed it on my iOS7 device then all the pages are getting rendered together. I have  rechecked HTML of all my pages manually and by taking only one Scrollable page at a time. When i take 2 or more Scrollable pages then all are getting rendered together. Following is one console error that i'm getting

"`[ERROR] error JSON.stringify()ing argument: TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures.`"

Don't know whether is it because of this error. Tried solving this error too by following below post but didn't get success

[thomasvendetta](http://thomasvendetta.com/article/2012/09/error-jsonstringifying-argument-typeerror-jsonstringify-cannot-serialize-cyclic)

[Post on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19872221/getting-error-json-stringifying-argument-typeerror-json-stringify-cannot-ser)

Please help. This bug is freaking me out.

Comment: "JSON.stringify()ing" I'm getting this error when i run it on iPad...and dojoInit function is not getting called.... strange!!

Comment: Its working fine on iPhone.

Comment: In your worklight project, there's a www folder. If you expand dojo/nls under that do you have the following files:
core-web-layer_en-us.js, core-web-layer_ROOT.js, mobile-ui-layer_en-us.js, and mobile-ui-layer_ROOT.js?

Comment: Hi nsand! under the mentioned path by you its showing only core-web-layer_en-us.js and mobile-ui-layer_en-us.js file to me. There are no ROOT file under it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your Dojo library project, copy `toolkit/dojo/dojo/nls/core-web-layer_ROOT.js` and `toolkit/dojo/dojo/nls/mobile-ui-layer_ROOT.js` into your Worklight project's `www/dojo/nls` folder.

Additionally, if your phone is not set for the en-US locale, you may need to copy additional resources from the Dojo library project. For example, if your phone is configured for French, you'd need to copy `toolkit/dojo/dojo/nls/core-web-layer_fr.js` and `toolkit/dojo/dojo/nls/mobile-ui-layer_fr.js` into your Worklight project's `www/dojo/nls` folder as well.

Comment: Thanks Nsand!! I have gone through this link

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rad.worklight.doc%2Ftopics%2Fcdojolibprjsetupwl.html
It Works